# How to make image css

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I want display image like this:

[image]

but original image like:

[image]

how make css for display like image 1, please tell me..

Comment: What you have tried so far? share your code.

Comment: ya, but image output be squashed..

Comment: Please edit your question and add HTML/CSS code you have so far.

Comment: you are using bootstrap..??

Comment: @NikhilGhuse yes, I use bootstrap..

Comment: @RahmatSaepuloh did you tried any of the following...?

Answer (score 0):

Then try this if you are using bootstrap

```
   <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/v4BWm.png" alt="img" class="img-thumbnail img-responsive">
```

[Demo JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/niks2060/9ggehk5d/)

Answer (score 0):

Html

```
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/v4BWm.png"  class="ImgOuter" >
```

css

```
.ImgOuter
{
  padding:10px;
  background-color:#d1e0e0;
  border-radius:2%;
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
}
```

[Demo JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/patelsumit5192/vank5dcj/)

Comment: its not responsive dude

Comment: I have updated my answer. 
If this works for you then please click up arrow (This answer is useful). This helps other if anyone needs it

Comment: @NikhilGhuse it's responsive